# Pandas/Dask Check if value in column else add another value

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am using Pandas/Dask data frames. I have a data frame of ~87 million rows. I have two columns (call them columns A and B) that I essentially want to say 'if 'x' is not in a row in column A, add 'n' to the value.'

I can of course try using itertuples, but I was just wondering if there was a quicker was to check if a value is there, and if not add something else for 87 million records.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df.loc[df.A == "x", "B"] += n
```